# How do you define the integral over a torus?

Tags: integration

This is a rather simple question but I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this. The question is how does one define
$$
\int_{\mathbb{T}^d} f(x)dx?
$$
where $\mathbb{T}^d:=\mathbb{R}^d/\mathbb{Z}^d.$

My understanding is that every function on the torus can be extended periodically. Does this mean that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{T}^d} f(x)dx=\int_{(0,1]^d} \textbf{f}(x)dx?
$$
where $\textbf{f}$ is the periodic extension of $f$?

Comment: One way: $\mathbb{T}^d$ is a compact group.  Use Haar measure for that group.  Yes, it is the same as the formula you state.

Comment: Since you are only integrating over one period, there is no need for a periodic extension of $f$.